# How to give user permissions to view "AllItems.aspx", but NOT to "DispForm", "NewForm" and "EditForm"?

Tags: document-library

I would like to show all list items to some users. I do not want to give these users too much permissions to view "DispForm", "NewForm" and "EditForm". They need only to see the "AllItems.aspx" page to see some columns of this items.

How can I implement this?

If there is some webpart like CQWB or something else I can show only some columns of the items it is also ok.

Comment: In SharePoint you can set permissions to Pages. Since these are also page i believe you can set permissions. Open these pages in a new window, then select Page from ribbon then set permission.

Comment: I try it, but I dont see the pages tab when I go to for example : https://portal.myCompany.net/teams/siterequests/Lists/Offshore/DispForm.aspx. Are you sure this is possible?

Comment: I just tried, its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a page and add the list with the view that you want to display. You could then restrict the user from seeing newform, editform and dispform by removing the permission level 'View Application Pages' from their permission group.  Keep in mind that doing this will prevent them from viewing newform, dispform, etc from all lists in the site.

Alternatively, you could add a 'Search Results Web Part' to a page and [configure it to only query that list](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/06/how-to-configure-the-search-results-web-part-to-use-a-new-result-source-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) and then hide the list from the UI.

Comment: Thanks James, what a great solution. It works perfect.. I cloned the "view only" permission level and removed the "View Application Pages" permission :)

Comment: You can can break inheritance on that specific list and then apply the custom 'view only' permission level to the appropriate groups.